# do nodejs run 2 asyn task faster than 2 sync task on 1 core cpu?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

The question about came up with my understanding:

- nodejs run event-loop on a single thread, single core.
- but nodejs server can access other core via Cluster uses child_process to interact inter-process communication instead of using thread pool if can, and this makes it faster.
- If I run nodeJs on 1 core CPU, child_process can't access other core and it will process slower than 2 sync task?

And I read about this blog, is that `Libuv create 4 thread` mention below is running on event-loop thread (mean single core that run nodejs server?)

[nodejs event loop - medium](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c)

> Libuv by default creates a thread pool with four threads to offload asynchronous work to

Comment: Even on single core async tasks would probably perform better than sync task, you'll see big difference when the task involves calls over the wire or I/O operations for example.

Comment: okie thank you, I was misunderstood on that.